# How to add a filter in a custom manager?

Tags: django, django-custom-manager

I'm stuck with adding a filter to a custom manager in Django. This is my current custom manager that is working:

```
class VoteAwareManager(models.Manager):

    def _get_score_annotation(self):
        model_type = ContentType.objects.get_for_model(self.model)
        table_name = self.model._meta.db_table
        return self.extra(select={
            'active': 'select active from %s mh where mh.main_id = %s.id and mh.active = true and mh.date_begin = (select max(date_begin) from euvoudebicicletaengine_mainhistoric where main_id = mh.main_id) and mh.date_end >= now()' % (MainHistoric._meta.db_table, table_name),
            'row_num': '(row_number() over(order by (SELECT COALESCE(SUM(vote / ((extract(epoch from now() - time_stamp )/3600)+2)^1.5),0) FROM %s WHERE content_type_id=%d AND object_id=%s.id) DESC))' % (Vote._meta.db_table, int(model_type.id), table_name), # To know the position(#number) on the front page
            'score': 'SELECT COALESCE(SUM(vote / ((extract(epoch from now() - time_stamp )/3600)+2)^1.5),0) FROM %s WHERE content_type_id=%d AND object_id=%s.id' % (Vote._meta.db_table, int(model_type.id), table_name)
                }
        )

    def most_loved(self,):
        return self._get_score_annotation().order_by('-score')

    def most_hated(self):
        return self._get_score_annotation().order_by('score')
```

I need to add a filter to the `most_loved` and `most_hated` to `active=True` that will be the SQL equivalent to `where active=true` in the main sql expression.

Any clues on how to do it?

Answer (score 1):

I think you probably need to write a SQL view (to replace your `extra()` function) and create a new [unmanaged model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/options/#managed) for the view (including `active` as a field in your model).

As in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245956/creating-django-model-for-existing-database-sql-view) question. Or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/507795/can-i-use-a-database-view-as-a-model-in-django) (possibly out of date) one.

Then use the view in your `_get_score_annotation` and add a [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#filter) to the queryset you're getting from that function.

```
def _get_score_annotation(self):
    return ContentTypeView.objects.filter(# any filtering you need)

def most_loved(self,):
    return self._get_score_annotation().filter(active=True).order_by('-score')
```

Comment: Hi Aidan. Thanks for the reply. Adding the filter in that way gives me an error: "Cannot resolve keyword 'active' into field. Choices are: ...". It looks like the I cannot use the extra fields in the WHERE clause. Any clues on how to do it in another way? Best Regards,

Comment: OK, I see the issue (I thought that seemed a bit straight forward).